# Check if VPN tunnel is tunneling connections with windows command line

Tags: powershell, command-line, vpn

I would like to check with windows command line or powershell if the openVPN tunnel on my machine is actually tunneling the connections or not (maybe due to a fault of the server). Running Windows 8.1.

I used to check this by going on any website that tells me my ip and check whether the ip is the one of the VPN server or not.

Now, I have a php script showing me the ip of the client on a port 8888 of the server, so that with windows firewall I block all the connections except those on port 8888 or the port of the vpn, I connect to the vpn, go on http://serverip:8888/script.php and check the ip. If the IP is the one of the vpn, then I'm connected and I can reset the firewall to the normal values, otherwise there is a problem and the connection is not being tunneled through the vpn.

I'd like to automate this task.

(FYI: the "block connections" and "unblock connections" on the firewall is performed via command line)

Comment: sorry, but very vague. You need to post some code, and explain what problems you are having. If not script, at least the cmds you execute from the command line. Did you try editing a script file to include them? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is simply to ping an internal site like intranet and check if you get a reply.
Otherwise, you can also add a test record in you post-vpn dns and check if the computer can resolve this test alias/hostname.

Comment: But I will get a response from an internal site even if the VPN doesn't tunnel the connections. The vpn might be connected, but unable to tunnel the connections (for whatever reason).
Can you explain better the second option?

Comment: What do you think about analyse a Tracert to check if your VPN Gateway is in the route?

I don't really understand why are you using a VPN if you already have access to internal sites...

Anyway, if you want to check if your connection transit through the VPN, the way to implement it will depend on one important thing:
Your VPN uses split tunneling or all the traffic goes through?

Comment: If you want to know if the VPN is mounter or not:
- try to access a site or ping a ressource that may be accessed only outside or inside the VPN
- analyze traceroute to see if your VPN gateway is in the route
- check the default gateway given by the dhcp server
- analyzing traceroute to see if your VPN gateway is in the route
- install an software firewall on your machin that allows adaptive rules like (if vpn gateway can be reach, deny local traffic and forward all to VPN)

Comment: Could you suggest a software to do so?